# Laravel Authentication, different for clients and users

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm working a site for invoicing and inventory, and I need two different kinds of Authentication, one for clients and other one for users (sellers, administrator). I know it would be easier to have a single table `Users` with a field like `user_type`, instead of having `Users` and `Clients` but I need this two tables individually because they interact each other and also have differents behaviors. What do you think I should do for an efficient authentication?

Comment: If you want to retain your sanity then you should keep all users in the same table. In other words, I would recommend that you do not create two different ways to authenticate users. If you are worrying about security then you should worry about the actual security, not the user table in the database.

Comment: And how can this table interact with an `Invoice` table, where should be the id of the user and also the id of the seller as foreign key?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is permission groups. This way you can add a group called clients and one as administrators or sales. I would look @ [Sentry by Cartalyst](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry). I use this to manage 13 groups. This also has the ability manage permissions and write conditional statements on permissions.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what your software does but it looks like you need to do some reading on pivot tables.

My guess is that you have "clients", "Users", and "Invoices"? and need each invoice to have a client and a user? Maybe several of either?

All of you members, client or user, in the same table. Make sure to give them all a 'user id' of some sort.

'Invoice' table, same as the last two.

Pivot table would be member_to_invoice. This would be a many to many pivot (i think) and would simply have (invoice_id, client_id, user_id).

This would give each invoice a member and a user. The drawback of this would be that a member type is only set by the invoice. So there wouldn't be a way to have a client log in that was different then a users. Though that might not be a drawback depending on what the system does.

You could set it up the other way as well with another table 'member_type' and pivot that off the member table. This would give you separation in the member types. Then you wouldn't really need the member_to_invoice pivot unless you needed multiple users or clients attached to a single invoice.